# Is anyone using DropBox to synch data between iPhone an iPad

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, synchronization, dropbox

I have a universal app which uses simple pLists for data storage and would like an end user with both an iPhone and iPad have the settings/data synched. I think using DropBox may be the easiest way to do this.

I am wondering if anyone out there has successfully done anything similar to this and might want to share their experience.

Thanks,

John

Comment: Are you happy to specify the use of third party software as a requirement of using your app? Because I'm pretty sure Apple won't be...

Comment: Use iCloud, it's meant for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use iCloud .... its just perfect for your present problem.

Comment: Great. Thanks, I better start reading up now on how to do this.